# Python socket server not connecting in raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I am writing a programm for chatting through python sockets. My raspberry pi (running raspbian) has the static ip 192.168.1.3 and my pc 192.168.1.4

My server.py

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

def send_msg(client, msg):
    client.send(bytes(msg,"utf-8"))


def listen_send(client1, address, name):
    while True:
        msg = client1.recv(1024).decode()
        if msg != '':
            for c in clients:
                if c != client1:
                    send_msg(c, "%s (%s) "%(name,address)+msg)


number = int(input("Enter number of connections"))
clients = []
addresses = []
names = []

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port = 25001
s.bind(('192.168.1.3', port))
print ('Socket binded to port 25001')
s.listen(number)
print('Socket is listening')

while len(clients)< number:
    cl, addr = s.accept()
    names.append(cl.recv(32).decode())
    clients.append(cl)
    addresses.append(addr[0])
    print ('Connection from ', addr[0])
    send_msg(cl, "Waiting for other connections")


for i in range(0,len(clients)):
    send_msg(clients[i], "Connection established\nYour ip is %s"%addresses[i])
    Thread(target=listen_send, args=(clients[i],addresses[i],names[i],)).start()
```

My client.py

```
import socket
from threading import Thread


def send(s):
    while True:
        msg = input()
        s.sendall(msg.encode())

def listen(s):
    while True:
        msg = s.recv(1024).decode()
        if msg != '':
            print(msg)


s = socket.socket()
port = 25001
ip = input("Enter ip\n")
s.connect((ip, port))
name = input("Enter your name\n")
s.send(bytes(name, "utf-8"))

while True:
    msg = s.recv(1024).decode()
    print(msg)
    if 'Connection established' in msg:
        break

t1 = Thread(target=send, args=(s,))
t2 = Thread(target=listen, args=(s,))
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

**When i run the server in my pc just by changing the s.bind ip to 192.168.1.4 i can connect to my client.py from raspberry but when i run server in raspberry i cannot connect from my pc (i get TimeoutError: [WinError 10060])**

Comment: Does ping work from both devices to the other? Could be a gateway (Layer 3) issue.

Comment: Yes ping works.

Comment: can you run `iptables-save` on your raspberry ?

Comment: You can run `netstat -anopt` on Pi and see if server LISTENing port is bound to localhost or interface IP.

Comment: Yes it shows nothing

Comment: Are you using any firewall?

Comment: I just noticed i was using ufw....

Comment: Check your rules by using ufw status. If you dont see port 25001 in allowed ports then it is a firewall issue

Comment: I see only 22,80 and 443

Comment: Turns out it was just a firewall issue. If you have ufw, allow a port by using sudo ufw allow (insert port here, in your case 25001) / (insert tcp/udp) or choose an ip address with sudo ufw allow from (insert ip address, in your case 192.168.1.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with firewall. Solved this with ufw allow port 25001.